# Avoid adding bash command to history

Tags: bash

I'd like to avoid adding a command to bash history, because it contains sensitive data.

```
$ export SECRET=sensitive
$ echo $SECRET
```

How can I avoid that the `export` command is added to the history?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the value `ignorespace` in the shell variable `HISTCONTROL`, e.g. by setting it in `~/.bashrc` like this.

```
HISTCONTROL=ignorespace
```

Now you can prefix the command line with a space, and it will be ignored:

```
$  export SECRET=sensitive  # Intentional blank at the beginning of the line
$ echo $SECRET
```

From the Bash docs:

> **HISTCONTROL**
>
> A  colon-separated  list  of values controlling how commands are
>                 saved on the history list.   If  the  list  of  values  includes
>                 **ignorespace**,  lines  which  begin with a **space** character are not
>                 saved in the history list.  A value of **ignoredups**  causes  lines
>                 matching the previous history entry to not be saved.  A value of
>                 ignoreboth is shorthand for **ignorespace** and **ignoredups**.  A value
>                 of **erasedups** causes all previous lines matching the current line
>                 to be removed from the history list before that line  is  saved.
>                 Any  value  not in the above list is ignored.  If **HISTCONTROL** is
>                 unset, or does not include a valid value, all lines read by  the
>                 shell parser are saved on the history list, subject to the value
>                 of **HISTIGNORE**.  The second and subsequent lines of a  multi-line
>                 compound  command  are  not tested, and are added to the history
>                 regardless of the value of **HISTCONTROL**.